# VS Code Terminal: How to use pip version of activated venv=

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, terminal, pip, conda

how can I instruct VS Code to use the `pip` version linked to the activated venv in VS Code Terminal?

**What I tried**

After activating the same `conda virtual env` in both Mac Terminal and VS Code Terminal,
when I execute `which python` both return the same, correct value:

- Both: `/Users/myself/miniconda3/envs/vs-code-3.10/bin/python`

However, when I execute `which pip` only Mac Terminal returns the correct value and this causes packages installation via VS Code Terminal:

- Mac Terminal (Correct): `/Users/myself/miniconda3/envs/vs-code-3.10/bin/pip`
- VS Code Terminal (Wrong): `/usr/local/bin/pip`

Important note: in VS Code I also manually selected the correct Python Interpreter (see screenshot).
[image]

**Versions**

- macOS 13.1
- VS Code 1.74.1
- conda 22.9.0

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have activated the conda environment and check the version using the command in the terminal where the environment was activated.

[image]

Select the conda interpreter, and create a new terminal to activate the environment.

[image]

Or use the `conda activate` command to activate the environment

Comment: Thank you. Concerning your first point, I already confirmed that both Mac Terminal and VS Code Terminal use the same Conda environment. Concerning your second point, it is also confirmed that VS Code Terminal is using the right interpreter (provided screenshot).

Comment: This should be related to environment variable configuration.